# Is there an Rstudio keyboard shortcut to open up the file that contains the source code to a function you've written?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have multiple packages of my own making that I usually have loaded into my R sessions, as well as various functions specific to a small project stored in various utils files. Say I know the name of a function but want to open the particular file housing that function, for reading & debugging purposes. In pyCharm, for example, you can just select the name of that function and press `ctrl-b`. Is there any sort of keyboard shortcut or function to find (and ideally autmatically open) the file / line that contains the definition of my function of interest?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe section ["Go to function definition"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200710523-Navigating-Code):

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are within a package then F2 will navigate to the source file of functions defined within that package (it would be nice if you could also go to other packages but that doesn't work yet). You can also use Ctrl+. to do a typeahead search of all functions in the package (and navigate from the list).

Answer (score 1):

The only soltuion that I am aware of is that you can select a function name in RStudio (it is actually enough to place the curser somewhere inside the function name) and then press F2. This will open up a tab called `Source Viewer` in the source pane, where you can look at the function definition. It does not, however, open the file where the function was defined. This means that you can not edit and save the function.

I don't know for sure that there is no funcionality to open the file where the function is defined, but I have good reason to suspect that there is not. When you source a script, the R expressions in that script are evaluated. If it contains function (or variable) definitions, these are stored in memory and will be available in the R session for further use. These R objects do not know where the code that defined them is stored (or whether they were just defined from the command line), so I don't see an immediate way how RStudio could know, where to look for the file containing the definition and open it.

Comment: If you source a file with a function `fn` in it, then `attr(attr(fn, "srcref"),"srcfile")` will provide the path to the source file.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for shortcut to access file, press CTRL key and double click the file name to get it opened.